.Net 8.0 after immediately running it displays "Cookie.Expiration is ignored, use ExpireTimeSpan instead"
I have Converted my mvc application from .net core 2.2 to .net 8.0, but when it is running, it is not showing login page instead of it is throwing error like below,

I am using Redis session. I have set configuration like below,
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(option =>
{
    option.Configuration = Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureRedisConnection");
    option.InstanceName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration.GetSection("SessionSettings")["RedisInstancePrefix"]) ? Configuration.GetSection("SessionSettings")["RedisInstancePrefix"] : "CrmStep_";                
});

services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
    options.IOTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration.GetSection("SessionSettings")["IOTimeOut"]) ? Convert.ToDouble(Configuration.GetSection("SessionSettings")["IOTimeOut"]) : 1440);
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration.GetSection("SessionSettings")["IdleTimeOut"]) ? Convert.ToDouble(Configuration.GetSection("SessionSettings")["IdleTimeOut"]) : 1440);
});

services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Login";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
            options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        });


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCookiePolicy();            
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();

Please any one help to fix this, Thanks!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

According to the error message, you could find you should use the options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24); instead of   options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);since the ExpireTimeSpan will ignore the Expiration.
This options.ExpireTimeSpan controls how much time the authentication ticket stored in the cookie will remain valid from the point it is created. The expiration information is stored in the protected cookie ticket. Because of that an expired cookie will be ignored even if it is passed to the server after the browser should have purged it.
This is separate from the value of Expires, which specifies how long the browser will keep the cookie.
Use below codes and it will work well.
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Login";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            //options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
            options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        });


Thanks a lot! But I have already completed this yesterday itself same like you suggested.
